# React-Redux: Action Dispatch on button click not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

On click of Button my Action is not getting dispatched. Below are all the files viz - action, reducer, root reducer, configSTore, Index and Component.

Please help me why my action is not getting dispatched on button click

Actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const requestURL='JSONUrl';
let responseData = '';

export function fetchRequests() {
    axios.get(requestURL)
    .then((res) => {
        responseData = res;
    });
    return responseData;
}

export const fetchDataAction = () => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA',
        data: fetchRequests()
    };
}

export function fetchDataSuccessAction(err) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        err
    };
}

export function fetchDataErrorAction(err) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR',
        err
    };
}
```

Reducer.js

```
export function fetchDataReducer(state = [], action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'FETCH_DATA':
                return action.data;
            default: return state;
        }
}

export function fetchDataSuccessReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.err;
        default: return state;
    }
}

export function fetchDataErrorReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR':
            return action.err;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

RootReducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { fetchDataAction, fetchDataSuccessAction, fetchDataErrorAction}
from '../actions/fetchData';

export default combineReducers({
    fetchDataAction,
    fetchDataSuccessAction,
    fetchDataErrorAction
});
```

configStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/rootReducer";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
    const enhance = applyMiddleware(thunk);
 
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,        
        enhance
    );
}
```

INdex.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Header from './App';
import configureStore from './store/configureSTore';
import {CounterApp} from './counter';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <Header favcol="yellow"/>   
      <CounterApp /> 
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

My Component File

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchDataAction, fetchRequests } from './actions/fetchData';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 export class CounterApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    btnClick = () => {
        return this.props.fetchDataAction;        
    }
    render() {   
          
    return (        
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello</h1>                                       
            <div>
                <h1>Fetch Data click below</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction}>
                Fetch Data
                </button>
                {this.props.datafetchedFromApi}            
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({    
    datafetchedFromApi: state.data
    
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchDataAction: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction())  
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterApp);
```

On click of Button my Action is not getting dispatched. Below are all the files viz - action, reducer, root reducer, configSTore, Index and Component.

Please help me why my action is not getting dispatched on button click

Comment: You have to call the mapped action for it to work. Like, `this.props.fetchDataAction()`

Comment: @AvinashThakur - on doing that below is the Error
TypeError: this.props.fetchDataAction is not a function

Comment: Can you provide an example on https://codesandbox.io/ ? There's something wrong and it isn't clear from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer got too long, so first part is if you wanna fully understand why things went south. If you just want your problem solved so you can finally go pee, the second part is for you :).

***First Part*** (Basically what asynchronous programming in JavaScript is, so any questions to what are asynchronous tasks in JS can be referred to this answer.)

Okay a couple of problems detected here. As others have pointed out make sure all the paths for imports are correct. Now assuming they are all correct, here's what you need to do to solve your problem.

First let's take a look at the top of your component file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchDataAction, fetchRequests } from './actions/fetchData';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
...
```

And then the block where you have called fetchDataAction:

```
...
<button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction}>
   Fetch Data
</button>
...
```

Here what you have done is `this.props.fetchDataAction`, I don't see you passing fetchDataAction as a prop to this component, so it's most probably *undefined* that's why you get an error `TypeError: this.props.fetchDataAction is not a function` because of course *undefined* is not a function.
This was the first mistake I noticed.

Now, moving on to the second one. I'm gonna start with this

***Dispatching actions in redux is synchronous.***
So you cannot do something like the following:

```
export default function SomeComponent(props) {
  const fetchAction = () => {
     let payload;
     //wait for 5 seconds for the async task(the setTimeout below is an async task) to populate the payload with data.
     setTimeout(() => payload = "This is my data", 5000); 
     //then return the action object
     return {
       type: 'Data',
       payload,
     };
   }
   const handleClick = () => {
       dispatch(fetchAction());
   }
   return (<>
    <Button onClick={handleClick} />
  </>);
}
```

The above will not throw any errors, but will certainly not do what I want it to do. The above will dispatch the following action object:

```
{
  type: 'Data',
  payload: undefined
}
```

which ofcourse is not what I want the payload to be.

And that's exactly what you're doing. Take a look at your `fetchDataAction` and `fetchRequests` functions:

```
...
let responseData = '';

export function fetchRequests() {
    axios.get(requestURL)
    .then((res) => {
        responseData = res;
    });
    return responseData;
}

export const fetchDataAction = () => {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA',
        data: fetchRequests()
    };
}
...
```

Now I'll compare with the example I've given above:

- Here your `responseData` is analogous to my `payload`
- Your `fetchRequests` function is analogous to my `setTimeout`

Looks familiar? I'm sure by now it does. Plain simple answer as to why it doesn't work is that you're performing an async task, in your case you're making a network request with axios.get(requestUrl)...

Network requests are async(now if you don't know what async things are, check out https://javascript.info/callbacks which gives you idea about what those are. Also check out a video on it by TheNetNinja https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcQyJ-gxke0 ), in simple words, \network requests take some time to get finished(just like setTimeout).

So the axios.get request takes some time to get the response back from the server. Now the other tasks(below it) won't wait for that request to get completed, instead js will execute those tasks immediately without waiting for the response.

I know this answer is getting too long. But I want you to understand, because trust me I have made the same mistakes before :).

So in your `fetchRequests` function:

```
export function fetchRequests() {
    axios.get(requestURL) --- (1)
    .then((res) => {
        responseData = res; --- (2)
    });
    return responseData; --- (3)
}
```

In line 1, you start an async task. Remember the function inside `then` block will execute only after sometime. So the responseData is still undefined. Instead of line (2), line (3) will execute first, cause as I told you earlier, js won't wait for the response from the server(the technical wording is 'the thread doesn't get blocked by network request'.) So basically you're returning undefined from this function.

Also see this video by JavaBrains. He uses an excellent analogy to understand async tasks in js, and you might also learn about what the event loop is and about single threaded-ness of javascript.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EI7sN1dDwcY

Now the ***Second part*** (I really wanna go pee):
Replace(I've pointed out where I have made changes)

Your component file with this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchDataAction, fetchRequests } from './actions/fetchData';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class CounterApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
  btnClick = () => {
     return this.props.fetchDataAction;        
  }
    render() {       
        return (        
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Hello</h1>                                       
                <div>
                    <h1>Fetch Data click below</h1>
                    <button onClick={() => fetchDataAction()}> //this is the only change here
                        Fetch Data
                    </button>
                    {this.props.datafetchedFromApi}            
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({    
    datafetchedFromApi: state.data  
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchDataAction: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction())  
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterApp);
```

And then in your `action.js` file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const requestURL='JSONUrl';
let responseData = '';

export function fetchRequests() { 
    return axios.get(requestURL) //change is here
    //removed return responseData and the 'then' block
}

export const fetchDataAction = () => { 
    return dispatch => {                        //almost whole of this function is changed and that's it
    fetchRequests().then((res) => {
       responseData = res;
       dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA',
            data: responseData
       })
    });
  };
}

export function fetchDataSuccessAction(err) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
        err
    };
}

export function fetchDataErrorAction(err) {
    return {
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_ERROR',
        err
    };
}
```

Now it should work. Tell me more if it doesn't. Remember this answer is assuming that you have all your functions imported properly into your files. I'll be making edits if this doesn't answer your question.

So the answer was to use 'thunk' - an official "async function middleware" for redux.

Also see this to learn more about handling 'async actions' and also using redux thunk:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk

Comment: can't you just avoid this whole thunk thing and use async/await instead...like make `fetchRequests` function async and await it's call in `fetchDataAction` function, and then dispatch the action object. That should work.

Comment: you explained no doubt very well, but just following above 2 changes as you mentioned - NO ERROR is coming but on Button Click Just nothing is happening....

Comment: @AEmilia post your project in github, and link me to it, if you don't mind sharing your codes. I'll have a look at it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction()}>
```

Also if you need to dispatch the url from your components you can do this way

```
    <button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction(url)}>


    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    fetchDataAction: (url) => dispatch(fetchRequests(url))
     };
     };
```

And in Action.js

```
   export function fetchRequests(url) {
    axios.get(url)
    .then((res) => {
    responseData = res;
    });
   return responseData;
   }
```

Comment: using above as you mentioned i am getting this Error - TypeError: this.props.fetchDataAction is not a function

Comment: doing console.log(this.props) - its showing as empty Object {}. Maybe Props is not initialized correctly?

Comment: Yeah check that and also verify the imported path for 
import { fetchDataAction, fetchRequests } from './actions/fetchData'; This should work

Comment: This could probably be the issue try this   import fetchRequests from "./actions/fetchData";     and verify if the path of fetchRequest where the url called is correct

Comment: In the above code the path for fetchRequests seems to be in Action.js can you check if the path where you have this function is provided right

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction()}>
```

<button onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction}>
Here you are trying to return the function definition alone ,not call the fetchDataAction onclick use  `onClick={() => this.props.fetchDataAction()}` or pass a separate handler for the onclick as good practice.

Comment: using above as you said i am getting below error....TypeError: this.props.fetchDataAction is not a function

Answer (score 0):

For the other issue you have mentioned TypeError: this.props.fetchDataAction is not a function is because of the curly brackets used while importing fetchRequests

Remove the curly brackets

```
import fetchRequests from "./actions/fetchData";
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: Attempted import error: './actions/fetchData' does not contain a default export (imported as 'fetchDataAction').

Comment: You need to import only fetchRequests and not fetchDataAction

Comment: Remove the above import and just place import fetchRequests from "./actions/fetchData";

Comment: Removing curly braces will call the function defined in mapDispatch not the Action. It will not work. It will not import the Action which is already an export

Comment: I think you are almost there just remove import { fetchDataAction, fetchRequests } from './actions/fetchData'; you don't need to add import for fetchDataAction and only place import fetchRequests from './actions/fetchData';  Let me know if this works

Comment: Tried not working  used your code ' import fetchRequests from "./actions/fetchData"; ' 
 ERROR                                                                                                                     
 ./src/counter.js
Attempted import error: './actions/fetchData' does not contain a default export (imported as 'fetchRequests').

Comment: As per this error there is no fetchRequests in that path i.e in fetchData.js. Is that the class that contains fetchRequests function as above I guess it's in ur Action.js class can you verify the path where this function is and recheck the path